# reinterpret_cast member function pointer to void(*&)()

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, reinterpret-cast

Member function pointers can not be `reinterpret_cast` to function pointers. (GCC requires the `-pedantic-errors` flag to enforce that, though.)

However GCC, Clang and MSVC seem to agree that casting a *member function pointer* to a *reference to function pointer* is ok. See the following example:

```
#include<type_traits>

struct A {
    void f() {}
};

int main() {
    auto x = &A::f;
    auto y = reinterpret_cast<void(*&)()>(x);
    // auto y = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(x);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(y), void(*)()>);
}
```

[Godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/xWsu8K)

This program compiles on all three compilers, but fails to compile on all (with pedantic flags) when the out-commented line is used instead of the previous one.

I don't see any rule in the standard allowing this conversion. Is the program ill-formed and the compilers fail to diagnose it or is the program well-formed?

If the latter, what is the exact conversion sequence, where does the standard allow it and can the function pointer be converted back to the original type in order to call it or is the use of the reference for initialization of `y` already undefined behavior?

Comment: What happens if `A::f` is virtual?

Comment: @PeteBecker It doesn't seem to make a difference to the compilers.

Comment: C++ may have a sharp edge, or two.  This seems like one of them.

Comment: @uneven_mark -- okay, thanks. Red herring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast<T&>(x)` is equivalent to `*reinterpret_cast<T*>(&x)`.

In other words, `reinterpret_cast<void(*&)()>(x)` performs type punning on the pointer itself.

Accessing the result of this cast violates strict aliasing and causes undefined behavior, as usual.

---

> I don't see any rule in the standard allowing this conversion.

Here:

> [**[expr.reinterpret.cast]/11**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#11):
>
> A glvalue of type `T1`, designating an object `x`, can be cast to the type “reference to `T2`” if an expression of type “pointer to `T1`” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to `T2`” using a `reinterpret_­cast`.
>   The result is that of `*reinterpret_­cast<T2 *>(p)` where `p` is a pointer to `x` of type “pointer to `T1`”. ...

Since `reinterpret_cast` between pointers to object types (in your case, between pointers to pointers (to [member] functions)) is always allowed, it's also allowed in your case.

Comment: Oh that was an obvious solution. I feel stupid for asking, but I suppose I should not delete an upvoted question. When I read that quote earlier, for some reason I thought that the member function pointer wasn't an object, but of course it is.